# Ignoring contents of folder not working with Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

Ok, I'm trying to ignore the *contents* of a directory but not the directory itself but I'm having trouble doing it.

Inside the directory itself when I right click and go to `TortoiseSVN -> Properties` I have the entry `svn:ignore '*.*'` - from what I have read that is the correct way to do it.

However when I add files to this directory they are *not* ignored; when I go to `Add` all the files show up to be added and then committed.

What am I doing wrong!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normaly i use the svn-command propset to do it and this one ignores all files whithin the folder 'folder'

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*" folder
```

Try setting the Tortoise-Properties to `svn:ignore "*" folder`

Comment: Since i can't test it right now, i can only say that it works with my projects and i use TortoiseSVN. And `*.*` ignores only files with a dot in it, but that may be ok for you

Comment: Oh ok, well I can give it a try I guess.

Comment: Well I changed it but when I tried a commit on the folder it said nothing could be commited; if it worked shouldn't it be deleting all the files in that directory?

Comment: No it shouldn't. It just ignores them for add. Otherwise you would always loose all ignored files on commit. If you want to delete them, you could choose "delete unversioned items" in TortoiseSVN

Comment: What I mean is that all the files in that folder are currently versioned as I added them by mistake before; usually when you ignore something in SVN it will delete on commit if it's already versioned, but these won't.

Comment: Sorry, Brett, but that is simply not the case with SVN: it does *not* delete already versioned files when you ignore them. Uwe is correct that it *only* ignores them for add. So use TortoiseSVN's `Delete(keep local)` command (on the extended context menu) on the files in question, then commit, to resolve your issue.

Comment: @msorens I don't mean it physically deletes them, I mean it deletes them from being versioned. I just tested it and I was right. When you go to the context menu and select "Unversion and ignore" it will come up with options such as `Delete by name` etc

Comment: (1) I understood that you did not want to delete them; that's what "keep local" means. (2) Now you are changing the game in midstream: `unversion and ignore` is quite different from `ignore`. So you were right in what you wanted, not in what you asked for. :-)

Comment: @msorens Ok fair enough. :)